# Find answers posted by particular user for my questions

Tags: support, answers, search

Assume I asked 100 questions, and one particular user answered 10 of my questions.

I want a list of those 10 questions answered by that particular user.

I want to know just for interest. For example I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), and would like to know if any such top user has answered my questions.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: A properly phrased SEDE query could answer this, but I'm not sure the regular search box can (either you're going to use `is:q user:me` or `is:a user:other_guy`, but I can't think of a way to combine them. I know there's a small bug hat sometimes allows you to get answers for `is:q` searches which was brought up recently here on MSE, but even if you could abuse that, you're still left with the problem of the conflicting user constraints).

Comment: @JonW just for interest, means i saw users with top reputations :

http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all , i want to know is any questions of these users or answered by other top users in this page.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Site search does not support such queries.

Data Explorer does: see [Questions by someone answered by someone else](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461132/questions-by-someone-answered-by-someone-else)

Example: [questions by Jeff Atwood answered by Shog9](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/461132/questions-by-someone-answered-by-someone-else?asker=1&answerer=811).